# Save RData to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: r, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm recently learning how to read & write files to Azure Blob Storage using R on Azure Databricks. Are there any tutorials on how to save RData file to Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: You might start with the [AzureStor vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureStor/vignettes/intro.html).

Comment: Thanks neilfws! There is rawConnection and textConnection to transfer in-memory R objects using AzureStor library. textConnection seems not to work for RData format. Any hint on how to use rawConnection to write RData file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of AzureStor now has a `storge_save_rdata` function:

```
bl <- blob_endpoint("https://myacct.blob.core.windows.net", key="mykey")
cont <- storage_container(bl, "mycontainer")
storage_save_rdata(iris, mtcars, container=cont, file="myblob.rdata")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to upload the data frame as a CSV directly from the R environment using AzureStor package.

```
w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.csv(ds,w_con)
r_con <- textConnection(textConnectionValue(w_con))
close(w_con)
upload_blob(container, src=r_con, dest=paste0("check_",ds[1, "Claim Number"], '_',ds[1, "Claim Type"], ".csv"))
close(r_con)
```

For more details, see the [operations](https://rdrr.io/cran/AzureStor/man/blob.html) on a blob container or blob.

Comment: Thanks Pamela! One advantage with RData format is that we can save multiple data frames or save a list of objects to one RData file, which can avoid saving multiple csv files. I'm curious if Azure blob storage supports the functionality of saving RData.